# lambda (block) slot via Objective-c in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, objective-c-blocks

I need to mix C++ and Objective-c(++) files. I've stack in the next problem:
I have the code:

```
connect(menu_action,&QAction::triggered, [=]()
{
//do_smthing();
});
```

But when I am trying to compile file that contains this code (.mm file) I've got "excepted expression" error.

> excepted expression and the compiler point to symbol `=` after symbol `[`.

**How can I rebuild this code into Objective-c?**

Comment: Do you turn on c++11 features of your compiler?

Comment: @SiyuanRen in .pro file I've added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`. When I am compiling this code in a similar .cpp file - all is fine. But I need make .mm file from .cpp.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is bad. This should read: `connect(menu_action, &QAction::triggered, [=]{do_smthing();});`

Note the end parenthesis before the closing semicolon.

It's worth saying that if you are just calling a function in your lambda you should prefer function pointers to lambdas. This will preserve Qt's maintenance of the signals and slots and you'll be able to call `sender()` in your slot.

Comment: "Note the end parenthesis before the closing semicolon": I did mistake, I am sorry(
When I deleted "()" the error still exist.
P.S. I have more than one function, but thank You for useful info!

Comment: @AntonKosobutskiy If this solved your problem I'd go ahead and accept this answer. If not you can edit the question or add a comment. Also for follow up questions you can ask a new question and if You provide the link here I'll try to come answer.

Comment: "When I deleted "()" the error still exist."
This not solved my question. How I suppose to comment this? I mean, which of information do You need? file.mm / objective-c(++) / qt / connect signal and lambda (block). How can I supplement info?

Comment: @AntonKosobutskiy Ah got it. So the `()` shouldn't make a difference if it's there or not: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda note that the 4th definition is simply a lambda taking no arguments. Anyway, I think the next thing we should look at is the actual error. Can you edit your question and add that?

Comment: I guess the [c++ and qt] it's not a point. [Objective-c(++) and qt] is the real point. I saw Your link - and I think "[capture-list]" - is the reason for error.

Comment: @AntonKasabutski So I'd expect Objective-C to compile this fine, but you may need to spell out the variables you need to capture by value explicitly. So your lambda would look something like `[this, foo, bar]{do_smthing();}`